# Using powershell windows azure commandlets, how to I execute Reset-RoleInstance and wait for the operation to complete

Tags: powershell, azure, powershell-2.0

How to I execute Reset-RoleInstance and wait for the operation to complete...

I have been attempting to use the windows azure powershell commandlets to execute Reset-RoleInstance followed by | Get-OperationStatus -WaitToComplete.

So the documentation says "This operation executes asynchronously. To determine whether the Management service has finished processing the request, call the Get-OperationStatus cmdlet with the operation ID returned by Reset-RoleInstance, and optionally wait for completion by specifying the –WaitToComplete parameter."

I have tried this version:

```
Reset-RoleInstance -ServiceName MyTodo -DeploymentSlot production -SubscriptionId $subsId -Certificate $cert –reboot | GetOperationStatus -WaitToComplete
```

but this has a type in "GetOperationStatus".  So when I replace with "Get-OperationStatus", PS complains that OperationId is null or empty.

"Get-OperationStatus : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'OperationId'. The argument
 is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the comman
d again."

So, next I try this version of the PS script...

```
Reset-RoleInstance -ServiceName $serviceName -DeploymentSlot Production -InstanceName $i.InstanceName -SubscriptionId $subid -Certificate $cert -Reboot -OutVariable out | Get-OperationStatus -OperationId out.OperationId -WaitToComplete
```

This time, Get-OperationStatus starts throwing errors...

**Get-OperationStatus : HTTP Status Code: BadRequest - HTTP Error Message: The operation request ID was not found** ... in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.PowerShell.Services.Common.GetOperationStatusCommand

**Get-OperationStatus : Object reference not set to an instance of an object**.... in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Samples.ManagementTools.PowerShell.Services.Common.GetOperationStatusCommand"*

I have also managed to print $out and OperationId is infact null BUT in the RoleInstances member of the output there is this value...
RoleInstances  : {Instance Name: MyService.MyWorker_IN_0 - **Operation Id: 6e87a07fb9a5474499aed3f9ebe99129**}

Here is the output of the $out variable...
"RoleInstances  : {Instance Name: MyService.MyWorker_IN_0 - Operation Id: 6e87a07fb9a5474499aed3f9ebe99129}
ServiceName    : ... my service name
SubscriptionId : ... my subscription id
Certificate    : ... my certificate info

OperationId    : 
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *Reset-RoleInstance*, it either reboots/reimages the instances of the deployment. 
 The whole operation as such does not have an ***OperationId*** but the individual ***RoleInstances*** have a corresponding ***OperationId*** each.

This is how the output of Reset-RoleInstance looks like:

```
PS > $operation = Reset-RoleInstance -ServiceName "MyServiceName" -DeploymentSlot "production" -Restart -SubscriptionId "MySubscriptionID" -Certificate $cert
PS > $operation
-
RoleInstances  : { Instance Name: MyInst1 - Operation Id: OpId1, 
-                  Instance Name: MyInst2 - Operation Id: OpId2 }

ServiceName    : MyServiceName
SubscriptionId : MySubscriptionID
Certificate    : [Subject]
-                ------- blah --------

-                [Issuer]
-                ------- blah --------

-                [Serial Number]
-                ------- blah --------

-                [Not Before]
-                ------- blah --------

-                [Not After]
-                ------- blah --------

-                [Thumbprint]
-                ------- blah --------

OperationId    : <NullOrEmpty>
```

As you can see the ***OperationId*** at the end is *NullOrEmpty*. So you should not be waiting on the ***OperationId*** of the *Reset-RoleInstance* but should be waiting on the ***OperationIds*** of the individual ***RoleInstances***
     Eg: OpId1, OpId2

```
PS > Write-Host "Rebooting the instances"
PS > $operation = Reset-RoleInstance -Reboot -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -ServiceName $ServiceName -DeploymentSlot "Production" -Certificate $certificate
PS > Write-Host "Waiting for all reboot operations to complete..."
PS > $operation.RoleInstances | % { Get-OperationStatus -OperationId $_.OperationId -WaitToComplete -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -Certificate $certificate }
PS > Write-Host "All role-instances have been rebooted"
```